# chrome rendering issue of hindi font

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Here is my simple html file which works great in firefox but reneders differently in chrome and shows distorted texts.
it works great in jsfiddle as well.
   https://jsfiddle.net/r96L5rhx/1/

even stackoverflow renders properly in below code but chrome shows distorted text

here is imgur link of chrome screenshot
      https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK5V1.jpg

```
<div class="content_box_main">
<div id="1071" style="margin:auto;text-align:center"><div class="content_box_1">
<div class="content_box_2z"><sup class="joke_icon"></sup></div>
<div class="content_box_3_title"></div>
<div id="content_box_3_text" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size: 3.0vw;height: 900px;padding:10px;line-height:120%;"><div style="margin-top:80px;margin-bottom:80px;">पति पत्नी लन्दन गये, पत्नी ने ईसा मसीह की स्टेच्यू<br/>
देखा तो उनके पैर छुए।<br/>
पति ये देख कर बोला कि तूने मेरे पैर तो आज तक नहीं छुए ।<br/>
पत्नी का सुंदर जवाब -- पहले तू लटक तो सही ..</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: i have tested in chrome . working fine . which version of chrome ?

Comment: Version 55.0.2883.87 m

Comment: make sure you have the appropriate char set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean it should be shown as Hindi text, but it shows wrong for you even in this post? For me it looks correct in Chrome. But in general you could better replace non-ASCII characters with their HTML codes to be sure. The "Entity" column on this site should be what you need, although probably not complete: http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/southasia/devanagari/devanagarichart ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20170706204845/http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/southasia/devanagari/devanagarichart))

This page does it automatically: http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your **`head`** section ,it's works fine.

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content_box_main">
<div id="1071" style="margin:auto;text-align:center"><div class="content_box_1">
<div class="content_box_2z"><sup class="joke_icon"></sup></div>
<div class="content_box_3_title"></div>
<div id="content_box_3_text" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size: 3.0vw;height: 900px;padding:10px;line-height:120%;"><div style="margin-top:80px;margin-bottom:80px;">पति पत्नी लन्दन गये, पत्नी ने ईसा मसीह की स्टेच्यू<br/>
देखा तो उनके पैर छुए।<br/>
पति ये देख कर बोला कि तूने मेरे पैर तो आज तक नहीं छुए ।<br/>
पत्नी का सुंदर जवाब -- पहले तू लटक तो सही ..</div></div></div></div>
  </body>
```